# update_all not updating all objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have in my application a scoring system that needs to update many objects at once. To ensure atomicity I'm using update_all to increase a counter

```
rids = ["1", "3", "5", "7"]
lids = ["2", "4", "6", "8"]

User.where(id: rids).update_all("points_right = points_right + #{points}")
User.where(id: lids).update_all("points_left = points_left + #{points}")
```

That was working with small number of objects, but now it keeps missing one or two objects.

What am I doing wrong?

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
Rails 5.1.3
```

Comment: You probably have some objects in your db with null `points_right/left` columns. For db `NULL + 1 => NULL` (checked on postgresql). Run `rails c` and check if you have any users with null points (`User.where("points_right is null or points_left is null").any?`)

Comment: What does points object contains?

Comment: Do you have a `default_scope` defined on `User`? Or do you use gems in your `User` model that might add such a `default_scope`? Btw. What is `points`?

Comment: Try and avoid sticking in literal values which can cause SQL injection problems. It's easy to side-step this and do it safely: `update_all([ 'points_right=points_right+?', points ])`

Comment: @Ptr not an option, the default field value is 0; @AakashGupta integers; @spickermann points are a integer, no, there is no override on `default_scope`; @tadman I don't have sql injection problems in here, this is a internal area of the system that no user has access and points will always be an integer

Comment: Code looks fine. If you are missing few objects I would check if you generate `rids` and `lids` properly. How do you generate them? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @Ptr I've checked `rids` and `lids` multiple times, I can't find the problem, manually i've never seen the problem, it only appears on resque workers and even so `rids` and `lids` are correct. Could it be a ruby bug?